# Passing global/method local variable to child process callback functions

Tags: node.js

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var events = require('events');
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

var batchListener = function batchFinishListener(batchName) {
    console.log('Finished : ' + batchName);
};

eventEmitter.addListener('batchFinish', batchListener);

function executeProject(batchFile) {
    const bat = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', batchFile]);

    bat.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
      console.log(''+data);
    });

    bat.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
      console.log(''+data);
    });

    bat.on('exit', (code, batchFile) => {
      eventEmitter.emit('Finish', '' + batchFile);
      console.log('Child exited with code ' + code);
    });
}
```

In the above code, in `bat.on(exit, callback)`  I need the variable batchFile to be passed to callback and that to be passed on to eventListener. How to do it?

**Edit:** This works well with the modification below

```
bat.on('exit', (code) => {
    eventEmitter.emit('Finish', '' + batchFile);
    console.log('Child exited with code ' + code);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding callback function parameter should helps:

```
// ...update
function executeProject(batchFile, callback) {
    const bat = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', batchFile]);

    bat.stdout.on('data', (data) => console.log('' + data));

    bat.stderr.on('data', (data) => console.log('' + data));

    bat.on('error', callback); // Capture possible error

    bat.on('exit', (code) => {
      callback(null, code, batchFile);
    });
}

// Usage example
executeProject(batchFile, (error, code, batchFile) => {
    if (error) {
        eventEmitter.emit('error', error);
    } else {
        eventEmitter.emit('something-happend', batchFile);
    }
});
```

**NOTE** Try not to use global references when it possible. Because it could make you code monolithic and not reusable.